# Play Framework File Upload is not working and giving error: Action not found

Tags: html, scala, playframework, sbt

I'm running application on Play framework 2.2.3. As I'm trying to upload a file/image into a given path. After hitting the Submit button, I'm getting the below error.Please let me know where I'm doing wrong ?

Error:

```
Action not found 
For request 'GET /routes.ApplicationController.upload?picture=Image.png'

App.html: 

@form(action = routes.ApplicationController.upload, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {

    <input type="file" name="picture">

    <p>
        <input type="submit">
    </p>

}
```

routes:

```
POST            /upload             controllers.ApplicationController.upload()
```

ApplicationController.java:

```
public static Result upload()
    {
        MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
        FilePart uploadedFile = body.getFile("picture");
        if (uploadedFile != null) {
           String fileName = uploadedFile.getFilename();
           String contentType = uploadedFile.getContentType();
           File file = uploadedFile.getFile();
           // file.renameTo(new File(play.Play.application().path().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName));
           file.renameTo(new File("D:/Test/images/" +fileName));
           return ok("File uploaded");
       }
       else
       {
           return badRequest("No file uploaded.");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should specified form method POST/GET

For request 'GET /routes.ApplicationController.upload?picture=Image.png'
here play looking for GET and you have in routes only POST

Comment: I've tried with post method in my html form, but it's giving: Action not found  For request 'POST /routes.ApplicationController.upload' . similarly for Get method also it's giving the above Error(Action not found For request 'GET /routes.ApplicationController.upload?picture=Image.png').